# Definition of class in c++

Tags: c++, class

Could somebody explain to me why this example doesn't work? I really don't know where the problem is.

```
class test{
    test();
    test(const int n);
    void show();
private:
    int number;
};

test::test(const int n){
    number = n;
}

void test::show(){
    cout << number << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    test a(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are errors:

```
main.cpp:33:1: error: ‘test::test(int)’ is private
 test::test(const int n){
 ^
main.cpp:43:14: error: within this context
     test a(10);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly all members u write inside class body are private by default unless u specify public , protected.   So in your case, member functions are private and u need to specify access qualifier as public before the functions u need to access outside the class.

**access modifiers help implement Encapsulation.**

Also you can access private members inside the class but not outside the class unless you use friend functions.

```
class test{

private:

  int number; //private member, Note: if I remove private from above this variable will still be private because by default it is private

public:
  test();//default constructor
  test(const int n);//parametrized constructor
  void show()const;//show/display function, its better if you put const, this cannot modify your data member of your class

};

test::test(const int n)
{
    number = n;
}

void test::show()
{
    cout << number << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    test a(10);


    return 0;
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting says that the method `test` in class `test` is **`private`**. This is because the default access modifier for `class` is `private` (and for `struct` it is `public`). So if you declare some members or methods in `class` and you don't specify the access modifier explicitly (`public`, `protected`, `private`), then it will be `private` by default.

Just change:

```
class test{
test();
test(const int n);
void show();
private:
    int number;
};
```

to:

```
class test{
public:                    // <--- THIS
    test();
    test(const int n);
    void show();
private:
    int number;
};
```

Comment: That does not explain the part of the question _why_ it doesn't work the way he did it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the default access qualifier for class members and methods is `private`. In other words, if you don't specify one, which is what you have done, it will default to `private`. The fact that several lines later you define another `private` segment does not change that. So what you need to do is add a `public` segment at the beginning of your class definiation and it will work as expected.

Conversely, if you had used a `struct` instead of a `class`, the reverse would apply.

Answer (score 0):

Class members are private by default so all your members are private and "private:" clause at the bottom is redundant. Just add "public:" after "class test {".

Answer (score 0):

constructor and all other member functions are private in your class You must write public: before writing thier definations!